# First Segment must be moveto

Tags: codenameone

I see Index out of bounds exception using the signature component in two different scenarios based on the log. Is this is  a known issue.

Code:

```
SignatureComponent signC = new SignatureComponent();
  signC.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                Image sourceImage = sign.getSignatureImage().scaledSmallerRatio(300, 100);
                Image mute = Image.createImage(sourceImage.getWidth(), sourceImage.getHeight(), 0xffffffff);
                Graphics g = mute.getGraphics();
                g.setAntiAliased(true);
                g.drawImage(sourceImage, 0, 0);
                act.setSignature(mute);
            }
        });
```

[EDT] 1:5:7,914 - Exception: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException - First segment must be a moveto

```
 java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException
    at com_codename1_ui_geom_GeneralPath.checkBuf:619
    at com_codename1_ui_geom_GeneralPath.lineTo:668
    at com_codename1_components_SignatureComponent_SignatureDialogBody_SignaturePanel.pointerDragged:488
     at com_codename1_ui_Component.pointerDragged:4088
     at com_codename1_ui_Form.pointerDragged:3355
     at com_codename1_ui_Display.handleEvent:2288
     at com_codename1_ui_Display.edtLoopImpl:1212
     at com_codename1_ui_Display.invokeAndBlock:1355
     at com_codename1_ui_Display.invokeAndBlock:1392
     at com_codename1_ui_Form.showModal:2308
     at com_codename1_ui_Dialog.showModal:1138
     at com_codename1_ui_Dialog.show:582
     at com_codename1_ui_Dialog.showPackedImpl:1434
     at com_codename1_ui_Dialog.showPacked:1350
     at com_codename1_ui_Dialog.showImpl:1094
     at com_codename1_ui_Dialog.show:1072
     at com_codename1_components_SignatureComponent_3.actionPerformed:229
     at com_codename1_ui_util_EventDispatcher.fireActionEvent:349
     at com_codename1_ui_Button.fireActionEvent:571
     at com_codename1_ui_Button.released:605
     at com_codename1_ui_Button.pointerReleased:709
     at com_codename1_ui_Form.pointerReleased:3503
     at com_codename1_ui_Component.pointerReleased:4621
     at com_codename1_ui_Display.handleEvent:2249
     at com_codename1_ui_Display.edtLoopImpl:1212
     at com_codename1_ui_Display.mainEDTLoop:1130
     at com_codename1_ui_RunnableWrapper.run:120
     at com_codename1_impl_CodenameOneThread.run:176
     at java_lang_Thread.runImpl:153
```

[EDT] 1:5:7,926 - Exception: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException - First segment must be a moveto

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException
    at com_codename1_ui_Display.invokeAndBlock:1379
    at com_codename1_ui_Display.invokeAndBlock:1392
    at com_codename1_ui_Form.showModal:2308
    at com_codename1_ui_Dialog.showModal:1138
    at com_codename1_ui_Dialog.show:582
            at com_codename1_ui_Dialog.showPackedImpl:1434
            at com_codename1_ui_Dialog.showPacked:1350
            at com_codename1_ui_Dialog.showImpl:1094
            at com_codename1_ui_Dialog.show:1072
            at com_codename1_components_SignatureComponent_3.actionPerformed:229
        at com_codename1_ui_util_EventDispatcher.fireActionEvent:349
        at com_codename1_ui_Button.fireActionEvent:571
        at com_codename1_ui_Button.released:605
        at com_codename1_ui_Button.pointerReleased:709
        at com_codename1_ui_Form.pointerReleased:3503
        at com_codename1_ui_Component.pointerReleased:4621
        at com_codename1_ui_Display.handleEvent:2249
        at com_codename1_ui_Display.edtLoopImpl:1212
        at com_codename1_ui_Display.mainEDTLoop:1130
        at com_codename1_ui_RunnableWrapper.run:120
        at com_codename1_impl_CodenameOneThread.run:176
        at java_lang_Thread.runImpl:153
```

Comment: Please post the relevant code and add the appropriate language tag

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a bug in the `SignatureComponent`, I added a workaround here: https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/commit/f402d1b27ade9560cd55db1a104f52e004fe1768

This change will be in the update today.

Comment: Sorry, I fixed the link but I also phrased it badly. I meant worked around it in the `SignatureComponent` code. It will be fixed in today's update